# Unable to access S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently uploading files to my S3 buckets just fine however when I access the uploaded files via a browser I get the following message:

`[0522/083134:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()`
`[0522/083134:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(567)] Could not load locale pak for en-US`
`[0522/083134:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(501)] locale resources are not loaded`
`[0522/083134:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()`
`[0522/083134:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(567)] Could not load locale pak for en-US`

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: Are you using AWS SDK or a different library?

Comment: I'm not using anything, just simply trying to request the file via url in a browser. The permissions are turned on for everyone to read.

Comment: Then that's a weird error to return on a simple HTTP GET request